# String faltando caracteres(do banco de dados para o php)

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, sql-server-2008

O que está acontecendo aqui é que uma string (varchar),vindo de uma consulta do banco de dados, está faltando caracteres quando vou passar pro php , o php ler até uma certa parte depois para. Quando faço uma consulta Utilizando o SQL Server Management Studio, a string está completa mas quando vou passar para o php, o php só ler ate uma certa parte.

```
SELECT Exemplo
from tableExemplo
where tableExemplo.Codigo = X
```

Fazendo isso  o SQL Server Management Studio a string apresentará o valor :
"VARIOS: COBRADO DA SEGURADORA EM 06/01/2020 E EM 22/01/2020 TODAS AS NFS 107909/1,111983/1,112375/1,112756/1,112793/1,112988/1,113117/1,113482/1,113580/1,114036/1,114039/1,114606/1,115956/1,116809/1,119221/1,120149/1121338/1,122063/1,122288/1,12454/1,125835/1,134878/1,142280/1,142282/1,145483/1,150156/1,152001/1,154225/1,154681/1,155069/1,161504/1,161690/1,"

No php o código está assim

```
function ExemploString($codigo){

return $this->db->query(" SELECT Exemplo
from tableExemplo
where tableExemplo.Codigo = $codigo";
}

$dataTeste = ExemploString(X);

echo"<pre>";
print_r($dataTeste);
echo"</pre>";
```

Ao executar o código acima
o echo e o print_r apresentará o resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (

           [Exemplo] => VARIOS: COBRADO DA SEGURADORA EM 06/01/2020 E EM 22/01/2020 TODAS AS NFS 107909/1,111983/1,112375/1,112756/1,112793/1,112988/1,113117/1,113482/1,113580/1,114036/1,114039/1,114606

        )

)
```

Só está imprimindo uma parte do conteúdo.
já tentei o utf8_decode, utf8_encode, tira a quebra de linha no select mas mesmo assim continua imprimindo incompleto.

Comment: Você pode colocar a string de conexão na pergunta? Alguns drivers limitam a quantidade de caracteres enviados. Por exemplo o FreeTDS limita a 255 caracteres, e para conseguir o texto inteiro você precisa fazer um cast da coluna para text: `SELECT CAST(Exemplo as TEXT) FROM tableExemplo where...`

Comment: No seu print_r($dbData), não deveria ser print_r($dataTeste) ?

Comment: Corrigido,obrigado

Answer (score 0):

A função print_r trunca uma string que possua mais de 1024 caracteres.
A solução é passar TRUE para o segundo parâmetro da função `print_r`

```php
echo '<pre>' . print_r ($bigArray, TRUE) . '</pre>';
```